# Laravel 5.4 Auth Change table for all Auth processes

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have created a custom login (not using default laravel auth) for some business design forced reason that i need to adjust. Is there a way that all Auth procedures (checking session, login, logout, etc..) will look into another table? My google research points me to config/auth.php to change the table value there but when I opened it, there is no 'table' value in the config so I added it manually

```
'table' => 'user_admin',
```

..unfortunately, nothing has changed. Session checking still checks in users table.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: if you have user_admin table just add this code to your User model `protected $table = 'user_admin';` as web guard uses `users` as provider and `users` provider have User as model class

Answer (score 0):

go to

> config/auth.php

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

You'll maybe also need to modify the validator method in the RegisterController

You can change the table name in the migration [file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php#L16) and then change the table name variable in the [User.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php) model.

**Example:**

```
   class MyTable extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The table associated with the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'my_table';
    }
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: I actually went to that file config/auth.php but I don't seem to get the point what part I need to modify to make it look to other table. Also, my model name is AdminUser and I just created a manual authentication (because of some dirty app design that they don't want to adjust with Laravel's auth) so I need to create a manual authentication and go through all this modification.

Comment: me ask file code config/auth.php and Model AdminUser